# Recuperar datos de formulario

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente formulario de html y un script

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Encontré un pequeño tutorial en YouTube donde se recuperan todos los datos de un formulario con este código, sin embargo me devuelve un objeto vacío, no se exactamente este mal, no tengo mucha experiencia en Javascript y hasta he pensado que me odia xD, o quizas tenga un pequeño fallo que no veo,de antemano Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, acepta la respuesta que más te haya ayudado para que la comunidad lo sepa. Si ambas te parecen exactamente iguales escoje la más antigua (el pistolero más rapido gana!).  Consulta este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas, y así colaborarás mejor con la comunidad, muchas gracias. (sino la pregunta quedará pendiente para siempre sin respuesta aceptada, y es una pena pues ambas son buenas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que ningún elemento del formulario tiene `name`.

A todos los elementos que necesites obtener su valor, simplemente agregarles un `name`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
      <select multiple class="form-control" name="exampleFormControlSelect2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente , muchas gracias , aun me queda por aprender mas de Javascript

Answer (score 2):

los objetos de los forms se generan con la propiedad name de los inputs/select/etc. Asi que tienes que ponerle un name a esos elementos, no necesariamente necesitan un id

```
 <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="exampleFormControlSelect1">
```

o solo el name

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="exampleFormControlSelect2">
```

Comment: Excelente , muchas gracias , aun me queda por aprender mas de Javascript